# Unexpected locking scroll using FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I have a problem with the scroll bar on the right of the screen. When I slide the mouse wheel down, it locks the page. Watch my pictures:

Before:

[image: This is before]

After:

[image: This is after]

The code of the menu bar:

```js
var scrollY = 0;
var distance = 40;
var speed = 24;

function autoScrollTo(el) {
  var currentY = window.pageYOffset;
  var targetY = document.getElementById(el).offsetTop;
  var bodyHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
  var yPos = currentY + window.innerHeight;
  var animator = setTimeout('autoScrollTo(\'' + el + '\')', 24);
  if (yPos > bodyHeight) {
    clearTimeout(animator);
  } else {
    if (currentY < targetY - distance) {
      scrollY = currentY + distance;
      window.scroll(0, scrollY);
    } else {
      clearTimeout(animator);
    }
  }
}

function resetScroller(el) {
  var currentY = window.pageYOffset;
  var targetY = document.getElementById(el).offsetTop;
  var animator = setTimeout('resetScroller(\'' + el + '\')', speed);
  if (currentY > targetY) {
    scrollY = currentY - distance;
    window.scroll(0, scrollY);
  } else {
    clearTimeout(animator);
  }
}
```

```css
.body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  top: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 98;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
}

li {
  top: 0px;
  font-family: odin rounded;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: left;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  transition: color 1s, background-color 1s;
  width: 19vw;
}

li:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

li a {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  li {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

img.logo {
  height: 55px;
  width: auto;
  top: 3px;
  left: 5px;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
}

.abc {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#barre {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  z-index: 99;
}

#barre a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#barre a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .sticky {
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="barre">
  <ul>
    <li class="abc" onclick="location.href = 'main.html';"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="NoMaD"></li>
    <li class="abc" onclick="location.href = 'main.html';">Menu</li>
    <li class="abc" onclick="location.href = 'members.html';">Membres</li>
    <li class="abc" onclick="location.href = 'calender.html';">Calendrier</li>
    <li class="abc" onclick="location.href = 'contact.html';">Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
  window.onscroll = function() {
    myFunction()
  };

  var sticky = barre.offsetTop;

  function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      barre.classList.add("sticky")
    } else {
      barre.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  }
</script>
```

And the code of the full calendar (which is very long) is on: https://fullcalendar.io/

This is the first time that I see a lock like this, it's very strange. But before that I put my menu bar, the calendar worked correctly.

I tried to see what's wrong, but I didn't find it.

Comment: do you have an error on your console ?

Comment: there isn't any error

Comment: please do you have an idea?